# Django 1.8 migrations not obeying routers in multi db setup

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration

I have a django project with migrated and unmigrated apps. I can be able to selectively migrate the migrated applications by running the command :

```
  migrate <app> --database <database>
```

However I can't do this for unmigrated applications which are thirdparty.
To be able to sync them I have to run the command without the specifying app

```
  migrate --database <database>
```

This though ends up with errors from other apps to be routed to different databases complaining that no table is synced.

Is this there anything I can do to resolve the issue. 
I appreciate the effort to answer this question.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: @Salvia yes I did by modifying my router and ensuring all applications are routed to a specific database.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try 
`python manage.py migrate 'nameoftheapp'`

Answer (score 0):

In fact django keep track of the migrations scripts already done in your DB. To check if the list of really applied and non applied migrations run:

```
python manage.py showmigrations --list
```

You will see a big `X` next to the migrations that have already been applied.
If the thirdparty migrations scripts are already applied just delete them from the table `django_migrations` in you database (created automatically by Django). And apply your migrations again:

```
migrate <app> --database <database>
```